# Django template and latex

Tags: django, templates, latex

I want to use Latex to create PDF files with my Django templates.

But, when it generates the PDF file, some characters are not encoded in a good way, especially the ' (apostrophe): Latex stops compiling and if I ignore the error, the output is &#39.

I'm French, so my Python files are UTF-8, my database UTF8-general-CI and I use those packages for Latex: *[utf8]{inputenc} [T1]{fontenc} [francais]{babel} {lmodern}*

All french accents are generated, so I don't know where the problem is?

Any idea?

Here is my view:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
def results_contact(request, checkup_id):
    ...
    title = get_object_or_404(Checkup, pk=checkup_id).name
    ...

    template_file = 'activities/results.tex'

    t = loader.get_template(template_file)
    context = Context({
              ...
              "title":    title,
              ...
              })

    ...
    f.write(smart_str(t.render(context)))
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/download_file/upload/checkups/%s.pdf' % basename)
```

And my template:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
...

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{...}
\name{My name}
\address{My address}
\lieu{My city}
...
\conc{ {{ title }} } %here is my variable
...
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

For example, if title=Visite d'Adam, the output will be

> Objet : Visite d&#39Adam

Here is the log:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> Visite d&
                        ##39;embauche
l.35 \conc{ Visite d&#39;Adam }
?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a result of [automatic HTML escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping). As you are not generating HTML, you can [turn this feature off](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#how-to-turn-it-off):

```
{% autoescape off %}
    \documentclass[11pt]{lettre}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    ...

    \begin{document}
        \begin{letter}{...}
            \name{My name}
            \address{My address}
            \lieu{My city}
            ...
            \conc{ {{ title }} }
        ...
        \end{letter}
    \end{document}
{% endautoescape %}
```